# Change positioning / direction of dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I am currently working on adding a dropdown menu to my website, which works mostly, however the dropdown menu drops to the right of the clicked image and goes off the page. I've tried searching for ways to reposition this and have tried adding a margin, `right: 0px;` etc. Nothing seems to have an effect on the dropdown.

```
.profile, .avatar{
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    border-radius: 50%;
    
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.show {display: block;}

JS here:

    function displayDropdown(){
        document.getElementById("dropDown").classList.toggle("show")
    }
    
    window.onclick = function(event) {
        if (!event.target.matches('.avatar')) {
            var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown- 
    content");
            var i;
            for ( i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
                var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
                if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                    openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post all relevant js/css code with your question. How are profile and avatar classes defined? Where is `displayDropdown` function ?

Comment: I made you a snippet - it is missing a function

Comment: Updated the post with js and profile/avatar CSS. Thanks for making the snippet but it was preventing me from posting my edit for whatever reason.

Answer (score 1):

changed positioning of dropdown to relative, which allowed me to use the `right:` and `top:` CSS to position it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to click an element and the dropdown "show", then make an `if, else` statement like so:

```js
var clickElement = document.querySelector(".element");
var dropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
var elementClicked = false


clickElement.addEventListener("click", function(){

  if (elementClicked == false) {
 
  dropdown.style.display = "block";

  elementClicked = true

} else if (elementClicked == true) {
   
  dropdown.style.display = "none";

  elementClicked = false

})
```

Comment: hasnt seemed to change anything, though I've noticed the current hover I have doesn't work either.